# Getting matrix instead of an array when performing fft

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I want to understand why I do not get an array while performing fft. I want to obtain for each frequency a magnitude, but get two amplitude instead.

```
sample_rate, recording = wav.read("Sample_747.wav") 
fft = np.fft.fft(recording) 
#print sample_rate,recording

def calculate_normalized_power_spectrum(recording, sample_rate):

    fft = np.fft.fft(recording) 
    number_of_samples = len(recording)        
    # sample_length is the length of each sample in seconds
    sample_length = 1./sample_rate 

     frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(number_of_samples, sample_length)  
     positive_frequency_indices = np.where(frequencies>0) 
     # positive frequences returned by the fft
     frequencies = frequencies[positive_frequency_indices]
     # magnitudes of each positive frequency in the recording
     magnitudes =abs (fft[positive_frequency_indices])

   return frequencies, magnitudes
```

when I do fft I get

```
   print fft
    [[ 1644.+0.j  1642.+0.j]
    [ 1642.+0.j  1644.+0.j]
    [ 1639.+0.j  1639.+0.j]
        ..., 
    [ 1704.+0.j  1702.+0.j]
    [ 1703.+0.j  1703.+0.j]
    [ 1701.+0.j  1701.+0.j]]
```

When i display the magnitude with my function ,i obtain two magnitude for each frequency

```
      frq,mag =calculate_normalized_power_spectrum(recording, sample_rate)
       print mag
        [[ 1642.  1644.]
        [ 1639.  1639.]
        [ 1638.  1640.]
              ..., 
        [ 2676.  2676.]
        [ 2674.  2676.]
        [ 2671.  2671.]]
```

Comment: Please provide some sample output recording for wav.read()

Comment: What does `recording` look like?  It seems you are assuming it is 1D but the fft output indicates that it's 2D.

Comment: You probably have a stereo file (i.e. two channels) as your input.

Comment: @Ajean thanks So when did this is a good way to do the fft as follows if you are in 2d  `fft = np.fft.fft(recording) `

Comment: @PaulR thanks So when did this is a good way to do the fft as follows if you are in 2d fft = np.fft.fft(recording)

Comment: Sorry - I'm just a python/numpy noob who happens to know a little bit about DSP etc - you probably want to split your stereo input file though and just process one channel at a time (or alternatively you can mix the two channels into a single mono buffer).

Comment: Why don't you print the type of the data before applying any math to it? `print np.shape(recording)`

Comment: @roadrunner66 If I print getting `(661500, 2)`

Comment: Numpy's fft by default takes a 1D fft along the *last* dimension only of any multidimensional array, so if your dimensions are `(661500, 2)`, you should add the `axis=0` keyword to your fft call. See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html) for the documentation. Past that you need to understand what is really in that wav file.